# [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "....". Expected String, returned function()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, vue-props

I have been getting this error today. I am using VUEX for the first time, and I am trying to use a Getter to find an element in an array. I assume that the problem must be in the second parameter (`title`) that I am passing in the first code snippet, or in the way that I call the `getErrorByMbId` function.

What I am doing in the store registering the Getter:

```
[GETTERS.GET_ERROR_BY_MB_ID]: state => title => {
  return state.submitErrors.find(e => e.meta.name === title)?.content
    .titleOfError;
}
```

Introducing the getter in the component with mapGetters:

```
getErrorByMbId: PRODUCT_GETTERS.GET_ERROR_BY_MB_ID
```

Then I call the getter here in a computed. The title parameter accepts a string, that's why I am passing 'Number'. Number should be the title of the error.

```
return this.getErrorByMbId('Number');
```

If I donnot use Vuex, and just have a function in the computed, my code works fine. But I want to use Vuex isntead. Example:

```
   numError() {
      return this.errors.find(
        e => e.meta.name === 'Number'
      )?.content.titleOfError;
    }
```

These are the errors in the console:

[image]

How it appears to the UI as an error message. Looks like it stringifies the function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: Accidentally registered the mapGetters in methods instead of computed, that's why it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Your function parameters seem to be the wrong way around. In your first snippet you are returning a function that takes a parameter `state` and returns a function that takes a parameter `title`, when you want to return a state selector (that is, a function that takes `state` as a parameter).

Try this, just switching the names of the parameters:

```js
[GETTERS.GET_ERROR_BY_MB_ID]: title => state => {
  return state.submitErrors.find(e => e.meta.name === title)?.content
    .titleOfError;
}
```

Comment: Getting the same error but now it is the other way around. In the error instead of function(title), I get a function(state)

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm very familiar with Vuex, but from the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access) it seems like `mapGetters` expects a String as value where you are passing a function. Try using `getters` instead.

Comment: I have used getters. I think I solved it. But I will look into it tomorrow. I had accidentally put the mapGetters in the methods instead of the computed. Can this be the case?